# If filter F converges to x then a subfilter converges to x

Tags: general-topology

In any topological space, why is the above true? For example, take $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology and let $\mathscr F$ be all the neighbourhoods of $0$; then $\mathscr F$ is a filter. A subfilter of $\mathscr F$ can be the filter that is produced by $(-1,1)$, which is the filter that contains every superset of $(-1,1)$. Then this subfilter does not contain $(-\frac12,\frac12)$ for example. I'm confused, can you point out where I'm wrong and maybe hint to the solution of this, if possible without the use of nets?

Comment: It *isn’t* true, as you point out. What is true is that if $\mathscr{F}\to x$, and $\mathscr{G}\supseteq\mathscr{F}$ is a filter, then $\mathscr{G}\to x$. In other words, you need to look at filters that are *finer* than $\mathscr{F}$, not *coarser* filters.

Comment: https://books.google.gr/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=filter+converges+to+x+then+subfilter+converges&source=bl&ots=pasVXsiWOD&sig=neFKNyUrh3xEfmjGpouRRez5CuM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0iJzWqZfQAhXJiiwKHcenA1kQ6AEIOzAG#v=onepage&q=filter%20converges%20to%20x%20then%20subfilter%20converges&f=false . I searched around and i found the same exercise as a lemma in this link, lemma 2.24. Maybe the term "subfilter" is not the obvious thing that i have in mind

Comment: It isn’t. I suspected that that was the problem. If you go back up to p. 33 you’ll find the definition: $\mathscr{G}$ is a subfilter of $\mathscr{F}$ if $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{G}$, i.e., if $\mathscr{G}$ is **finer** than $\mathscr{F}$. The authors emphasize that the order goes in the opposite direction from the one that you might expect from the prefix *sub-*. The reason for calling it a subfilter is that it behaves like a subsequence in terms of convergence.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was very confused.

Comment: You’re very welcome.